# Does the length of a varchar[] in Postgres refer to the maximum length of each element, or the total?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a column like so:

- Data type: `character varying []`
- Length: `2048`

Does the "length" refer to the maximum length *each element* can be, or the length of the *whole array*?

Looking at the SQL code, the column is defined as

```
character varying(2048)[]
```

Comment: The latter. Elements are counted per character not by bytes according to docs.

Comment: Do you mean `character varying(2048)[]` or `character varying[2048]` ?

Comment: The UI does not make it clear, however digging into the SQL, I find `character varying(2048)[]`

Answer (score 0):

The length is the maximum number of characters each array entry can have.

Given that obviously arbitrary limit, you had better chosen `text[]`.